How do I add alternative app icons for a SwiftUI tvOS app?
I am familiar with providing the main layered app icon for a tvOS project, but I cannot work out how to successfully add support for alternative layered icons in the info.plist and/or build settings for a SwiftUI (or Swift) tvOS project.
Whenever I check the result of UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons it returns false
I have witnessed other tvOS apps such as Plex successfully switch the app icon, so it must be possible to do.
What am I missing?
